# Using Instafeed with Squarespace: Instagram API issue

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, squarespace, instafeedjs

I have an issue when trying to implement instafeed with Squarespace... it works well with the client ID I generated from my personal instagram account, but when I try switching to another account and generating a new client ID to plug into the code, it doesn't work. Any thoughts? The second account I am trying with has way more followers, would that be a factor?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '-------------',
        clientId: '------------------------------',
        get: 'tagged', 
        tagName: 'anytag', 
        target: 'insta-grid',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        limit: '60',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        template: '<a class="lightbox" href="#{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}"/></a><div class="lightbox-target" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}"/><div id="lightbox-text">{{caption}}</div><a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a></div>'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you didn't configure the permissions correctly for your Instagram accessids. I would first check this.

But more importantly, why not use the built in Instagram Block from Squarespace? It does the exact same thing as Instafeed. https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543367